# find all `option select` jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

```
$('#divID').find('input[type=text]');
```

If the above statement is to find all the input text. How do I find all `select option` in the same div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `option` as tagname selector:

```
$('#divID').find('option');
```

or

```
$('#divID option');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divID").find("option").each(function()
{
    // Get one by one option here
});
```

OR

```
$("#divID").find("option");
```

OR

```
$("#divID option");
```

Comment: why there is need of select?? option will always come under select element.